next js 14 and i18n for i18next-http-backend
Please, help me to get translations from backend. I use next.js version 14 and i18next. For backend api I use i18next-http-backend.
These are my files:
i18n.js
import { createInstance } from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next/initReactI18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import i18nConfig from '@/i18nConfig';
const I18NextHttpBackend = require('i18next-http-backend');

export default async function initTranslations(
    locale,
    namespaces,
    i18nInstance,
    resources
) 
{
    i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();
    i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);
    if (!resources) {
        i18nInstance.use(
            resourcesToBackend(
                (language, namespace) =>
                import(`@/locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
            )
        );
    }
    await i18nInstance.init({
        lng: locale,
        resources,
        fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
        supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
        defaultNS: namespaces[0],
        fallbackNS: namespaces[0],
        ns: namespaces,
        preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales,
        serializeConfig: false,
        use: [I18NextHttpBackend],
    });
    return {
        i18n: i18nInstance,
        resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
        t: i18nInstance.t
    };
}

i18nConfig.js
const i18nConfig = {
    locales: ['am', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'am',
    backend: {
        loadPath: `${process.env.BACKEND_DOMAIN}/api/translations/all/{{lng}}`,
        reloadInterval: 1000,
        requestOptions: {
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        }
    },
    prefixDefault: true
}

module.exports = i18nConfig

For locale translations it's working well, but for backend api - it's not working.
